# How to stop a summation when a variable is small enough?

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation

I meet with a problem. I hope to get an infinite summation of $f1(x)/f2(x)$

which converges to zero. So my code is `Sum[f1[x]/f2[x],{x,Infinity}]` or `Sum[f1[x]/f2[x],{x,Infinity}]`. However, when $x$ is large enough, both $f1(x)$ and $f2(x)$ go to zero, and then I get an error: *"Infinite expression 1/0. encountered."*
Can I set a condition to stop the summation when $f2(x)<10^{-15}$?

Any solutions? Thank you.

The whole code is as following:

```
Clear["Global`*"];

userM = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16};
lengthM = Length[userM];
rateD = 1.;
rateU = 1.;
snrDdB = Table[i, {i, -15., 15., 1}];
lengthS = Length[snrDdB];
snrD = 10^(snrDdB/10);
lambdaD = 1/snrD;
lambdaU = lambdaD;
lambdaS = lambdaD/100;
throughputD = Table[0., {lengthM}, {lengthS}];
sumD = Table[0., {lengthM}, {lengthS}];
sumD1 = 0.;
sumD2 = 0.;
gammaInc[t_, k_] := 1 - Gamma[k, t]/Gamma[k];
sumD2com[h_, j_, m_, iM_, tD_, qU1_, qS1_] := (iM - m)/iM*
   Binomial[iM, 
     m]/(m + 1)*(gammaInc[tD, j]/gammaInc[tD, j - 1])^(iM - m - 
      1)*(1 - (gammaInc[tD, j]/gammaInc[tD, j - 1]))^m*
   gammaInc[tD, j - 1]^(iM - 1)*
   gammaInc[tD, j + h - 1]*(qU1*qS1^(m*(1 - qS1)) + 1 - qU1)^(h - 1);


Do[iM = userM[[i1]];
  ilambdaD = lambdaD[[i2]];
  ilambdaU = lambdaU[[i2]];
  ilambdaS = lambdaS[[i2]];
  thetaD = Exp[rateD*Log[2]] - 1;
  tD = ilambdaD*thetaD;
  qS1 = 1 - Exp[-ilambdaS*(Exp[rateU*Log[2]] - 1)];
  qU1 = (ilambdaU*(Exp[rateU*Log[2]] - 1))/(1 + 
      ilambdaU*(Exp[rateU*Log[2]] - 1));
  sumD1 = Sum[gammaInc[tD, k - 1]^iM, {k, 100}];
  sumD2 = 
   NSum[sumD2com[h, j, m, iM, tD, qU1, qS1], {h, 100}, {j, 100}, {m, 
     iM - 1}];
  sumD[[i1, i2]] = sumD1 + sumD2;
  throughputD[[i1, i2]] = rateD/sumD[[i1, i2]];
  , {i1, lengthM}, {i2, lengthS}];
```

Two problems will occur:

1) `gammaInc[tD, j - 1]` converges to zero which causes 1/0;
2) `gammaInc[tD, j] / gammaInc[tD, j - 1]` and `qU1 * qS1^(m*(1 - qS1)) + 1 - qU1` converge to zero and their power can be zero which causes 0^0.

Perhaps it's easier for me to use a piecewise function?

Comment: look at `NestWhile`

Comment: Can you post the code you are actually using, e.g. the definitions of `f1`, `f2`? You also have a syntax error in your `Sum`: you should use square, and not round, brackets to call a function, e.g. `f1[x]`.

Comment: @MarcoB I attached the whole code.

Comment: OK thank you for the code. That is a lot of code though! From your description, I seem to understand that your problems crop up during the evaluation of this expression in the `Do` loop: `NSum[sumD2com[h, j, m, iM, tD, qU1, qS1], {h, 100}, {j, 100}, {m, iM - 1}];` Is that correct? If so, you should reduce your code to a *minimal* example, with just enough code and definitions to reproduce the problem, but not so much that people will be scared off... :-)

Comment: Oh, did you know `GammaRegularized[]` is built-in? You'll be particularly interested in the *three-argument* form…

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using `NSum`? In your question, it seems to me that you try to sum numeric values (instead of analytically evaluating a sum) and I think `NSum` is better for this. Simple example:

```
f1[x_] := x;
f2[x_] := Exp[x];

NSum[f1[x]/f2[x], {x, 1, Infinity}]
(* 0.920674 *)
```

Comment: I tried it. Actually, my function is rather complex. When I use NSum, the error becomes "xxx is not numerical at point m = 1. "

Comment: @Samuel Question: Can you reduce your function to a very small example that shows the same error when using `NSum`? Then we might be able to inspect in detail what goes wrong. Question 2: Is your function numerical at `m=1`? Have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 4):

You can find when $f_{2}(x) = 10^{-15}$, and then calculate the summation:

```
f1[x_] := Exp[-x];
f2[x_] := 1/x;
mybound = 10^-15;
maxx = (x /. Solve[f2[x] == mybound, x])[[1]];
mysum = Sum[f1[x]/f2[x], {x, 0, maxx}]
N[mysum, 10]
(* 0.9206735942 *)
```

Comment: Oh, it's a good idea. My recent solution is using piecewise function. Yours seems more clear and easy.

Answer (score 3):

the `NestWhile` approach

```
f1[x_] := Exp[-x];
f2[x_] := 1/x
NestWhile[ {#[[1]] + f1[#[[2]]]/f2[#[[2]]] , #[[2]] + 1} & , {0, 1} , 
             f2[#[[2]]] > 1/1000 & ] // First // N
```

> 0.920674

( `NSum` is most certainly the better approach unless you have some peculiar functions )

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 2;
j = 2;
FixedPoint[Plus[#, f1[i++]/f2[j++]] &, f1[1.]/f2[1]]
```